# One or two roots of positive real numbers?

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

sorry for this basic question but I was just going through Rudin's Principles textbook, and it says in theorem 1.21 (p.10):

$\textit{For every real $x>0$ and every integer $n>0$ there is one and only one real $y$ such that $y^n=x$}$

But what about $x=4$, $n=2$? Then both $y=2$ and $y=-2$ satisfy the relation, no?

Thx a lot for any help on interpreting this!

Comment: +1 to your query, because even though the question is basic, your analysis, as is, **is correct**.  Either the book has a typo/mistake, or you've taken something out of context.  For example, change the last part to $\cdots y^{(1/n)} = x.$  Note that under this altered interpretation, the constraint outlawing $x < 0$ is required, because of the convention that **even** roots of positive numbers are always assumed to be positive.

Comment: You're right, there are two such $y$ when $n$ is even. If a proof of this "theorem" is given, you should be able to find the mistake - maybe they forgot to state a requirement like $n$ is odd or $y>0$.

Comment: Yes thanks, I think the author did assume that y is positive in the proof. It makes sense now. A bit weird not to include that condition in the statement though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right the theorem is stated incorrectly . The theorem does however hold if one adds the condition that $y>0$ .